# Multiqueries with python/mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sphinx

I'm using [MysqlDB](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/). Does it provide a way to execute multiple `SELECT` queries like [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) does? If not, is there a python library that would allow that?

There is `executemany`, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm working with Sphinx and trying to get its [batch queries](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-multi-queries) to work.

Comment: [`MySQLCursor.execute()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_MySQLCursor_execute.html) takes a `multi` argument which enables mutli-statements, so I imagine some Python packages avail themselves of that.  But why would you ever want to do so?

Comment: @eggyal: Thanks for the hint! Using oracle connector instead of mysqldb might be an option, but I'm curious if mysqldb provides something similar out of the box.

Comment: @eggyal It's useful for schema migration scripts :)

Comment: I just now realized that the OP is asking about doing multiple SELECTs. multi_query is useful for managing several table modifications over a team working on their local databases before deployment. Up, Down, that jazz.

Comment: @eggyal: added an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time to dig in the source code of `MySQLdb` and the answer is **YES** you can do multiple queries with it:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(user="username", db="dbname")
cursor = db.cursor()

batch_queries = '''
    SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=1;
    SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=2;
'''
cursor.execute(batch_queries)

print cursor.fetchone()
while cursor.nextset():  # iterate to next result set if there is any
    print cursor.fetchone()

cursor.close()
```

Tested successfully in my localhost. Hope it helps.

Comment: It definitely does! Thanks a lot.